# Copying the text from specified div area in a website

Tags: php, html, bash

This is the link: http://www.senecacollege.ca/ce/classes/
(You should choose 'all' from dropdowns to see full list of courses)

This link contains the course codes and course names of my school. I am working on a school project(website) and in this website other student should be able to choose their courses. So, I have to save the courses, which are in the website, into database and and gave users options in drop down or in something else to choose their courses.

The problem is, there are so many courses that I can't type with hand. So, I was thinking some kind of a script, which will get the necessary information from web site and save into a text file, from there I can write a script to copy courses into my database.

I've checked the source HTML code and I see that course code is written in a p tag which has "results-credential" as a class name and the course name saved in h3 tag.

Before, I wrote a script which reads the tab names from browser but I don't know how to do this for a specific HTML tag in body.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: The list in the link above is by 99% taken from a database, Why not dump that or even access it directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're goal is to extract everything from the inside a tag that looks like this: `<p id="results-credentials>course name to extract</p>"` you could use BeautifulSoup a Python library for parsing HTML and XML. The code would look something like the following, but you probably need to tweak a little for your use case.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html_doc)
course_name = soup.find_all(id="results-credentials")
```

I've used BS before and it's really easy, but I normally start to rethink my strategy when I find myself parsing HTML, because badly formatted HTML is a everywhere and can cause a lot of problems. If you have access to the database then I would pull the names from the database. But if you absolutely have to parse the HTML, BS makes it pretty simple.